# How do I redirect HTTP to HTTPS for some paths but not others?

Tags: nginx, https

For a given vhost, I want to redirect some routes/paths/URIs to HTTPS, while allowing others to be requested on HTTP.

Specifically, I want to allow Artifactory packages to be requested on HTTP, but require that the web UI be accessed via HTTPS.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your `server` block is listening for requests on both port 80 and 443. Then include a conditional on `$scheme` and a permanent `rewrite`.

So to force `/webapp` and (anything under it) to HTTPS, you would use:

```
server {
  listen *:443 ssl;
  listen *:80;
  server_name www.example.com;

  if ($scheme != 'https') {
    rewrite ^/(webapp(/.*)?)$ https://$http_host/$1 permanent;
  }

  # ...
}
```

Comment: One needs also to make sure that no HSTS headers are set for the server, otherwise everything will be on HTTPS.